# 2D drawing alpha onto the canvas is very slow

Tags: android, performance, canvas, alpha

I've been trying to add a translucent color overlay to my live wallpaper.  No matter what I try, I get very slow load times.  I've tried drawARGB, setting alpha in paint, and creating an alpha bitmap pixel by pixel.  All of these methods result in slow load times.  Heres my code:

```
public void draw()
        {

            long borderLoadTime = 0;
            long drawStart = 0;
            long drawEnd = 0;
            long whileLoopEnd = 0;
            long overlayStart = 0;
            long overlayEnd = 0;
            long holderTime = 0;
            long lockTime = 0;
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long drawCounter = 0;

            Canvas c = new Canvas();

            c = holder.lockCanvas();

            long canvasLoadTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (c != null)
            {
                if (borderToggle)
                    c.drawRGB(InfinityService.BORDER_RED,
                            InfinityService.BORDER_GREEN,
                            InfinityService.BORDER_BLUE);
                else
                    c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

                borderLoadTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                synchronized (grid)
                {
                    lockTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    for (GridRow row : grid.getImageGrid().values())
                    {
                        for (Box box : row.getRow().values())
                        {

                            drawStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

                            if (box.getImgLeft() < getWidth()
                                    && box.getImgTop() < getHeight()
                                    && box.getImgRight() > 0
                                    && box.getImgBottom() > 0)
                            {
                                c.drawBitmap(serviceContext.getImages().get(box.getPhoto()), 
                                        Math.round(box.getImgLeft()), 
                                        Math.round(box.getImgTop()), p);
                            }

                            drawEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            drawCounter += drawEnd - drawStart;
                        }
                    }

                    whileLoopEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }

                overlayStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

                if (overlayToggle)
                    c.drawARGB(InfinityService.OVERLAY_ALPHA,
                            InfinityService.OVERLAY_RED,
                            InfinityService.OVERLAY_GREEN,
                            InfinityService.OVERLAY_BLUE);

                overlayEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();

                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

                holderTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }

            Log.d(InfinityService.TAG, "CANVAS LOAD: "
                    + (canvasLoadTime - start) + " ms");
            Log.d(InfinityService.TAG, "BORDER LOAD: "
                    + (borderLoadTime - canvasLoadTime) + " ms");
            Log.d(InfinityService.TAG, "BITMAP DRAW TIME: " + drawCounter
                    + " ms");
            Log.d(InfinityService.TAG, "LOOP TIME: "
                    + ((whileLoopEnd - lockTime) - drawCounter) + " ms");
            Log.d(InfinityService.TAG, "OVERLAY LOAD: "
                    + (overlayEnd - overlayStart) + " ms");
            Log.d(InfinityService.TAG, "HOLDER UNLOCK: "
                    + (holderTime - overlayEnd) + " ms");
            Log.d(InfinityService.TAG,
                    "LOCK TIME: "
                            + ((overlayStart - borderLoadTime) - (whileLoopEnd - lockTime))
                            + " ms");
            Log.d(InfinityService.TAG,
                    "------------------------------------");

        }
```

Now here's some of the log entries for frames drawn.  Notice how drawARGB is resulting in such slow times.  In addition, the canvas lock and unlock calls also take a long time to finish.

```
11-10 16:09:34.803: D/InfinityService(10233): CANVAS LOAD: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:34.803: D/InfinityService(10233): BORDER LOAD: 1 ms
11-10 16:09:34.803: D/InfinityService(10233): BITMAP DRAW TIME: 4 ms
11-10 16:09:34.803: D/InfinityService(10233): LOOP TIME: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:34.803: D/InfinityService(10233): OVERLAY LOAD: 8 ms
11-10 16:09:34.803: D/InfinityService(10233): HOLDER UNLOCK: 1 ms
11-10 16:09:34.803: D/InfinityService(10233): LOCK TIME: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:34.803: D/InfinityService(10233): ------------------------------------
11-10 16:09:34.873: D/InfinityService(10233): CANVAS LOAD: 1 ms
11-10 16:09:34.873: D/InfinityService(10233): BORDER LOAD: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:34.873: D/InfinityService(10233): BITMAP DRAW TIME: 4 ms
11-10 16:09:34.873: D/InfinityService(10233): LOOP TIME: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:34.873: D/InfinityService(10233): OVERLAY LOAD: 17 ms
11-10 16:09:34.873: D/InfinityService(10233): HOLDER UNLOCK: 3 ms
11-10 16:09:34.873: D/InfinityService(10233): LOCK TIME: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:34.873: D/InfinityService(10233): ------------------------------------
11-10 16:09:34.953: D/InfinityService(10233): CANVAS LOAD: 1 ms
11-10 16:09:34.953: D/InfinityService(10233): BORDER LOAD: 2 ms
11-10 16:09:34.953: D/InfinityService(10233): BITMAP DRAW TIME: 3 ms
11-10 16:09:34.963: D/InfinityService(10233): LOOP TIME: 3 ms
11-10 16:09:34.963: D/InfinityService(10233): OVERLAY LOAD: 24 ms
11-10 16:09:34.963: D/InfinityService(10233): HOLDER UNLOCK: 3 ms
11-10 16:09:34.963: D/InfinityService(10233): LOCK TIME: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:34.963: D/InfinityService(10233): ------------------------------------
11-10 16:09:35.044: D/InfinityService(10233): CANVAS LOAD: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:35.044: D/InfinityService(10233): BORDER LOAD: 1 ms
11-10 16:09:35.044: D/InfinityService(10233): BITMAP DRAW TIME: 4 ms
11-10 16:09:35.044: D/InfinityService(10233): LOOP TIME: 2 ms
11-10 16:09:35.044: D/InfinityService(10233): OVERLAY LOAD: 24 ms
11-10 16:09:35.044: D/InfinityService(10233): HOLDER UNLOCK: 4 ms
11-10 16:09:35.054: D/InfinityService(10233): LOCK TIME: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:35.054: D/InfinityService(10233): ------------------------------------
11-10 16:09:35.164: D/InfinityService(10233): CANVAS LOAD: 1 ms
11-10 16:09:35.164: D/InfinityService(10233): BORDER LOAD: 1 ms
11-10 16:09:35.164: D/InfinityService(10233): BITMAP DRAW TIME: 5 ms
11-10 16:09:35.164: D/InfinityService(10233): LOOP TIME: 2 ms
11-10 16:09:35.164: D/InfinityService(10233): OVERLAY LOAD: 43 ms
11-10 16:09:35.164: D/InfinityService(10233): HOLDER UNLOCK: 15 ms
11-10 16:09:35.164: D/InfinityService(10233): LOCK TIME: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:35.164: D/InfinityService(10233): ------------------------------------
11-10 16:09:35.234: D/InfinityService(10233): CANVAS LOAD: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:35.234: D/InfinityService(10233): BORDER LOAD: 1 ms
11-10 16:09:35.234: D/InfinityService(10233): BITMAP DRAW TIME: 2 ms
11-10 16:09:35.234: D/InfinityService(10233): LOOP TIME: 1 ms
11-10 16:09:35.234: D/InfinityService(10233): OVERLAY LOAD: 18 ms
11-10 16:09:35.234: D/InfinityService(10233): HOLDER UNLOCK: 2 ms
11-10 16:09:35.234: D/InfinityService(10233): LOCK TIME: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:35.234: D/InfinityService(10233): ------------------------------------
11-10 16:09:35.304: D/InfinityService(10233): CANVAS LOAD: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:35.304: D/InfinityService(10233): BORDER LOAD: 1 ms
11-10 16:09:35.304: D/InfinityService(10233): BITMAP DRAW TIME: 2 ms
11-10 16:09:35.304: D/InfinityService(10233): LOOP TIME: 1 ms
11-10 16:09:35.304: D/InfinityService(10233): OVERLAY LOAD: 19 ms
11-10 16:09:35.304: D/InfinityService(10233): HOLDER UNLOCK: 1 ms
11-10 16:09:35.304: D/InfinityService(10233): LOCK TIME: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:35.304: D/InfinityService(10233): ------------------------------------
11-10 16:09:35.374: D/InfinityService(10233): CANVAS LOAD: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:35.374: D/InfinityService(10233): BORDER LOAD: 1 ms
11-10 16:09:35.374: D/InfinityService(10233): BITMAP DRAW TIME: 3 ms
11-10 16:09:35.374: D/InfinityService(10233): LOOP TIME: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:35.374: D/InfinityService(10233): OVERLAY LOAD: 7 ms
11-10 16:09:35.374: D/InfinityService(10233): HOLDER UNLOCK: 13 ms
11-10 16:09:35.374: D/InfinityService(10233): LOCK TIME: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:35.374: D/InfinityService(10233): ------------------------------------
11-10 16:09:35.444: D/InfinityService(10233): CANVAS LOAD: 1 ms
11-10 16:09:35.444: D/InfinityService(10233): BORDER LOAD: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:35.444: D/InfinityService(10233): BITMAP DRAW TIME: 3 ms
11-10 16:09:35.444: D/InfinityService(10233): LOOP TIME: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:35.444: D/InfinityService(10233): OVERLAY LOAD: 8 ms
11-10 16:09:35.444: D/InfinityService(10233): HOLDER UNLOCK: 11 ms
11-10 16:09:35.444: D/InfinityService(10233): LOCK TIME: 1 ms
11-10 16:09:35.444: D/InfinityService(10233): ------------------------------------
11-10 16:09:35.614: D/InfinityService(10233): CANVAS LOAD: 1 ms
11-10 16:09:35.614: D/InfinityService(10233): BORDER LOAD: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:35.614: D/InfinityService(10233): BITMAP DRAW TIME: 4 ms
11-10 16:09:35.614: D/InfinityService(10233): LOOP TIME: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:35.614: D/InfinityService(10233): OVERLAY LOAD: 117 ms
11-10 16:09:35.614: D/InfinityService(10233): HOLDER UNLOCK: 9 ms
11-10 16:09:35.614: D/InfinityService(10233): LOCK TIME: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:35.614: D/InfinityService(10233): ------------------------------------
11-10 16:09:35.844: D/InfinityService(10233): CANVAS LOAD: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:35.844: D/InfinityService(10233): BORDER LOAD: 1 ms
11-10 16:09:35.844: D/InfinityService(10233): BITMAP DRAW TIME: 3 ms
11-10 16:09:35.844: D/InfinityService(10233): LOOP TIME: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:35.844: D/InfinityService(10233): OVERLAY LOAD: 67 ms
11-10 16:09:35.844: D/InfinityService(10233): HOLDER UNLOCK: 108 ms
11-10 16:09:35.844: D/InfinityService(10233): LOCK TIME: 0 ms
11-10 16:09:35.844: D/InfinityService(10233): ------------------------------------
```

I notice a considerable decrease in performance on both of my devices when using the alpha color overlay.

Is this simply unavoidable as a downside of 2D android canvas drawing?  Would openGL help regarding this issue?